# Accessing webpages hosted in VM through IIS from Host while NAT connected

Tags: iis, server, ip, virtualbox

I´m really new to all of this and I can't grasp what I do wrong.

Details:
Windows 10 on Host
Windows server 2019 on VM.
I have 2 network adapters on VM, for the IPs 192.168.1.15 and 192.168.1.16 (for different websites).
Through IIS, I created the webpages. I can access them normally from guest browser. I cannot ping from host OS to these websites.

Steps I have done for setting up:

-In the first adapter from VM I set up the connection like this:
[First NAT adapter from VM ]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D4HY.png
Where the IP is 192.168.1.15
Subnet mask is default 255.255.255.0
Default gateway is the gateway that I got using ipconfig in host machine.
DNS server is the IP our teacher told us to use.

Now the VM doesn't have access to the Internet. And I cannot access the VM webpage using 192.168.1.15 on hosts browser(I also edited the hosts file in Host)

Sorry if something is not clear, but I dont know what I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Do you bind the specified ip address in the site Binding?

Comment: @samwu I did. The webpage is binded to the IP

Comment: I suggest you use default setting and it look like network related issue.